# HangFire recurring job for more than 31 days or more than 12 months do not work

Tags: cron, hangfire

We are using HangFire application to schedule reports and sometimes report can be run for every 40 days or every 20 months but CRON expression in HangFire does not have any support as day of month can be in range of 1-31 and months can be in the range of 1-12

Any idea how this can be achieved.?

Comment: Run the script once per day, and let the script calculate the interval since it last ran.  You can store the last run dates in a file.  If today's date is 40 days since last run, execute, otherwise exit.  Similar for months.

Comment: @Nic3500, Yah... storing last execution seems only option. Instead of having recurring schedule. I am planning have scheduled run where I will calculate the next schedule and storing the current one.